# Should I delete the snapshot folder of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I see that in the folder %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Snapshots there are older versions as shown below.

[image]

Each folder takes up 2.5GB of hard drive space !

Is there a safe way to delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome article
[Keep data during version rollback](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9917429?hl=en)
contains this information:

> Starting in Chrome version 84, Chrome Browser stores a snapshot of user information locally on devices after each major version update. By default, the three most recent snapshots are retained. You can use the [UserDataSnapshotRetentionLimit](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=UserDataSnapshotRetentionLimit) policy to override the default or stop keeping snapshots altogether (by setting the policy to zero). When you roll back to Chrome version 83 or newer and a snapshot has been stored, user data such as bookmarks and autofill data are restored from the snapshot.

This means that if you have no intention of rolling Chrome back to
an earlier version, this folder is not required.

However, as a precaution, rather than deleting the folder, I would
instead disable snapshots and let Chrome remove them.

For Windows,
[disabling snapshots](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::UserDataSnapshotRetentionLimit)
is done in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, path `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`
by setting `UserDataSnapshotRetentionLimit` to zero.